# How to get the correct sum while doing group by, alongwith a where clause on columns which populate randomly for rows within the group?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-analysis

I have, say, an 'order table' with multiple columns and thousands of rows. Each order id has multiple rows and "order value" column has mostly zeroes in all except 1-2 for each order. Now I need to find the summation of order value for each of the order IDs. I can simply use a sum(order_value) and do "group by" on order_id but the catch is that I also need to filter out the orders on the basis of two different columns. The filter condition values in one of the columns(Filter1 column in sample data) populate randomly and is also zeroes for rest of the rows within an order (just like "order value" column). So when I add Filter1 in where clause, the rows satisfying filter1 condition value are used while summing up but the "order value" for those rows could be zero (as "order value" is also populating randomly).

How to get correct sum of each order alongwith the filters applied.
Below is a sample data for two order_id - 6180811 and 6119188:

| Order_ID | Filter1 | Filter2 | Order_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6180811 | 0 | NULL | 0 |
| 6180811 | 888653 | NULL | 0 |
| 6180811 | 0 | type 1 | 0.5 |
| 6180811 | 0 | NULL | 0 |
| 6180811 | 0 | NULL | 0 |
| 6180811 | 0 | type 1 | 13.5 |
| 6119188 | 0 | NULL | 0 |
| 6119188 | 0 | NULL | 0 |
| 6119188 | 0 | NULL | 0 |
| 6119188 | 0 | type 2 | 1.5 |
| 6119188 | 888621 | NULL | 0 |
| 6119188 | 0 | type 2 | 15.5 |

Here is my sample SQL:

select
order_id,
sum(order_value) as total
from order
where Filter1 in ('888653','888621')
and Filter2 in ('type 1','type 2')
group by order_id;

Expected result:

| order_id | total |
| --- | --- |
| 6180811 | 14 |
| 6119188 | 17 |

Actual result:

| order_id | total |
| --- | --- |
| 6180811 | 0 |
| 6119188 | 0 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably going to need to have a JOIN and pre-aggregate the order by on its own merit, and the filter on its own.  Something like

```
select
      Totals.*      
   from
      ( select distinct
              order_id
           from
              order
           where
                  Filter1 in ('888653','888621') 
              and Filter2 in ('type 1','type 2') ) Qualified
      JOIN
      ( select 
              order_id,
              sum( order_value ) TotalOrder
           from
              order
           group by
              order_id ) Totals
         on Qualified.Order_id = Totals.Order_id
```

Comment: Thanks so much DRapp. This helped me get to the right result just by making minor change. I moved the Filter2 where clause condition from 'Qualified' to 'Totals' and it worked. (because both filter1 and filter2 condition values are almost never on the same line so had to decouple them.) Big thanks to you again.